# how to replace till x before and x after of match in php>

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, match

Forexample I have this text:

`i work as x in a company. i work as y in a company. i work as z in a company. i work as a in a company. i work as b in a company. i work as`

I want to match `i work as` and `in a company` and replace those text with `123` and `456` so final result will be:

`123 x 456. 123 y 456. 123 z 456. 123 a 456. 123 b 456. i work as`

Currently, I have been finding each sentence and using `str_replace()` which feels impossible for large texts.

NOTE: PLEASE SEE that the final `i work as` is not replaced because there is no end phrase `in a company`

UPDATE CODE:

```
if(isset($_GET['path']) && ($_GET['path']=="products.aspx")){
    $contents = str_replace("http://refund-advantage.com/https://player.vimeo","https://player.vimeo",$contents);
}

if(isset($_GET['path']) && ($_GET['path']=="LogonSave2007.asp")){
    $contents = str_replace("http://refund-advantage.com/logon2007.asp?Fr=Err","http://trialwelcome.com/clone/logon2007.asp?Fr=Err",$contents);
}
if(isset($_GET['path']) && ($_GET['path']=="MainMenu2007.asp")){
    $contents = str_replace("http://refund-advantage.com/https://www.refund-advantage.com/","http://trialwelcome.com/clone/",$contents);
}
if(isset($_GET['path']) && ($_GET['path']=="TalcMain2007.asp")){
    $contents = str_replace("http://refund-advantage.com/TALCPage1.asp","http://trialwelcome.com/clone/TALCPage1.asp",$contents);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried it?

Comment: Please post your code too.

Comment: I posted the code. I am doing that just one by one.

Comment: Did you try make it using regex
`$s2 = preg_replace("/in a company/", "456", preg_replace("/i work as/", "123", $input_lines));`

Comment: I'd rather just use `str_replace()` -- The output by your code is: `123 x 456. 123 y 456. 123 z 456. 123 a 456. 123 b 456. 123` I don't want the last `123` because there is no end phrase

Comment: Look at https://regex101.com/r/oxRU8d/1.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex for this:

```
/i work as(.*?)in a company/s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oxRU8d/1).

**Details**:

- `i work as` - a sequence of literal chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the first occurrence of
- `in a company` - a sequence of literal chars
- `/s` - the DOTALL  modifier that forces the dot to match line break chars
- `${1}` - in the relacement pattern, refers to the text captured with Group 1.

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/U4tuXE):

```
$str = 'i work as x in a company. i work as y in a company. i work as z in a company. i work as a in a company. i work as b in a company. i work as';
$result = preg_replace('/i work as(.*?)in a company/s', '123${1}456', $str);
echo $result;
```